# I'm trying to change h2 tag to the title of selected song using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, global-variables

I'm trying to change the h2 tag with the id title to the name variable. I want it to change with the corresponding song, and I can't seem to get it right. When the user clicks next song I am wanting to update the h2 tag with the current songs name.

```js
var songList = ["audio/classic.mp3", "audio/rococo.mp3", "audio/test.mp3"];
var name = ["One", "Two", "Three"];

var music = new Audio(songList);
var currentSong = 0;

window.onload = Jukebox;

function Jukebox() {
    music.src = songList[currentSong];
    music.play();
}

function togglePlay() {
    return music.paused ? music.play() : music.pause();
};

function stop() {
    music.pause();
}

function nextSong() {
    currentSong++;
    if (currentSong > 2) {
        currentSong = 0;
    }
    Jukebox();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Jukebox.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Shade" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <main>
        <header>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="container">
                <h2 id="title"></h2>
                <div class="page0ne">
                    <button onclick="togglePlay()" class="pause"><h1>Play</h1></button>
                    <button onclick="stop()" class="stop"><h1>Stop</h1></button>
                    <button onclick="nextSong()" id="next"><h1>Next</h1></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <script src="Jukebox.js"></script>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nothing in the posted code does anything to achieve what you are asking about in the question. Unless and until you write some code that finds the relevant tag and tries to set the text inside that tag nothing to do that will happen.

Comment: Ok, will do, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, if this is what you are looking for, but you can simply update the name of the song in the title h2 tag as done in the below snippet. Please let me know if that helps.

```js
var songList = ["audio/classic.mp3", "audio/rococo.mp3", "audio/test.mp3"];
var nameList = ["One", "Two", "Three"];

var music = new Audio(songList);
var currentSong = 0;

window.onload = Jukebox;

function Jukebox() {
    // Update value of title by the name of the song
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = nameList[currentSong];
    music.src = songList[currentSong];
    music.play();
}

function togglePlay() {
    return music.paused ? music.play() : music.pause();
};

function stop() {
    music.pause();
}

function nextSong() {
    currentSong++;
    if (currentSong > 2) {
        currentSong = 0;
    }
    Jukebox();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Jukebox.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Shade" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <main>
        <header>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="container">
                <h2 id="title">Song Name</h2>
                <div class="page0ne">
                    <button onclick="togglePlay()" class="pause"><h1>Play</h1></button>
                    <button onclick="stop()" class="stop"><h1>Stop</h1></button>
                    <button onclick="nextSong()" id="next"><h1>Next</h1></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <script src="Jukebox.js"></script>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I did document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = nameList[currentSong]; but I kept putting it in the function nextSong like an idiot. Thanks man.